# Send email with PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a function that is able to send email by sending it through PowerShell.

Using the `System.Management.Automation` reference I am able to use the PowerShell class that allows me to add PowerShell script that will send the email.

If I were to type it directly into the PowerShell window it would look like this:

```bsh
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('sender@email.com', $password)
Send-MailMessage -From 'sender@email.com' -To 'receiver@email.com' -Subject 'Heres the Email Subject' -Body 'This is what I want to say' -SmtpServer 'smtp.office365.com' -Port '587' -UseSsl -Credential $Cred –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

It is able to send an email but I how would I check if an email wasn't sent?

The function is below.

```cs
private void SendEmail()
{
    string from = "sender@email.com";
    string to = "receiver@email.com";
    string subject = "Heres the Email Subject";
    string body = "This is what I want to say";
    string server = "smtp.office365.com";
    string port = "587";

    //Password goes here
    string password = "PASSWORD";
    string pw = "ConvertTo-SecureString '" + password + "' -AsPlainText  -Force";

    string cred = "New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('" + from + "', $password)";
    string send = "Send-MailMessage -From '" + from + "' -To '" + to + "' -Subject '" + subject + "' -Body '" + body + "' -SmtpServer '" + server + "' -Port '" + port + "' -UseSsl -Credential $Cred -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess";
    string psScript = "$password = " + pw + System.Environment.NewLine +
                      "$Cred = " + cred + System.Environment.NewLine +
                      send;

    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddScript(psScript);

        // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

        // loop through each output object item
        foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
        {
            // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
            // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
            if (outputItem != null)
            {
                //TODO: do something with the output item 
                Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName);
                Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont want send it from C#?

Comment: The `Send-MailMessage` dont return anything just like `SmtpClient.Send`. At best you can try the `-DeliveryNotificationOption` flag. or trying to catch exception, but that will only allow you to see immediate failure (on sending to SMTP Server)

Comment: May want to change `string from` variable to something like `string fromUrl` . `from` is a keyword when using Linq

Comment: I believe either the message is sent, or Powershell / C# will throw an error stating what the problem is. So if you don't have any error, then the message was sent successfully.

Comment: You can use try/catch and catch the exceptions if there is any. It would be hard to debug blatantly like this. But capturing the exceptions would be the best idea to deal these things.

Comment: I tried using try/catch with an incorrect password and no internet connection but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to check for errors using ps.HadErrors

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
     //Add the powershell script to the pipeline
     ps.AddScript(psScript);

     // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
     Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

     //check for any errors
     if (ps.HadErrors)
     {
         foreach (var errorRecord in ps.Streams.Error)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(errorRecord);
         }
     }

 }
```