# How to send an email with an attachment in PowerShell code?

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to write a PowerShell code that sends an email to specified email adress. When i run the code it just displays

```
+ $SMTPClient.Send <<<< ($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Attachment, $Subject, $Bod)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Oh and btw this is my code

```
$EmailFrom = “Myemail@outlook.com”
$EmailTo = “Someonesemail@gmail.com"
$Attachment = "(Filepath)"
$Subject = “Test”
$Bod = “Test”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.outlook.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“Email”,“Pass”); $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Attachment, $Subject, $Bod)
```

Please help. Im suffereing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000217/send-email-with-powershell)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000217/send-email-with-powershell

Comment: SmtpClient is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1). Use [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7) instead.

Comment: Start with [replacing all smart quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6968270/1701026) it might lead to unexpected behavior depending on the PowerShell version you work with.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! (Also do you guys have any idea how to send it with an attachment?)

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like that first :

```
$Username  = "Myemail@outlook.com"
$EmailPassword = "YourRealPassword of your email"
$Attachment= "C:\Test.txt" # Example you can change its path here instead of "c:\Test.txt"
$EmailTo = "Someonesemail@gmail.com" 
$EmailFrom   = "Myemail@outlook.com" 
$Subject = "PowershellTest"
$Body= "PowershellTest"
$SMTPServer  = "smtp.outlook.com"  
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
$Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

---

***EDIT :*** Using PowerShell’s `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet

Refer to [How to Send Email with Office 365 Direct Send and PowerShell](https://adamtheautomator.com/office-365-direct-send-smtp/)

using PowerShell’s `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet :

You’ll first need to define a PowerShell PScredential object then provide all of the parameters that `Send-MailMessage` needs.

```
# Get the credential
$credential = Get-Credential
## Define the Send-MailMessage parameters
$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer                 = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port                       = '587' 
    UseSSL                     = $true
    Credential                 = $credential
    From                       = 'sender@yourdomain.com'
    To                         = 'recipient@yourdomain.com', 'recipient@NotYourDomain.com'
    Subject                    = "SMTP Client Submission - $(Get-Date -Format g)"
    Body                       = 'This is a test email using SMTP Client Submission'
    Attachment                 = 'C:\Test.txt' # Here you can change your attachment
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure', 'OnSuccess'
}

## Send the message
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

---

When you run the code above, you should receive an email received by the internal recipient (yourdomain.com) and the external domain (notyourdomain.com) with Attachment.

---

***IMPORTANT REMARK :***

If you encounter this problem while sending a mail with the smtp of google, you should take a look at this [Can not send mail using smtp.gmail.com, port 587 from vbs script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605803/can-not-send-mail-using-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-from-vbs-script?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can use batch and powershell to send an email :
First copy and paste this code as

***PS-Gmail-Sender.bat***

```
@ECHO OFF
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605803/can-not-send-mail-using-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-from-vbs-script/28606754#28606754
Title Sending E-Mail with Gmail Less Secure Applications using Powershell and Batch
SET GmailAccount="%~1"
SET GmailPassword="%~2"
SET Attachment="%~3"
REM We write our Powershell script 
CALL :WritePS
REM We execute our Powershell script .PS1 by passing arguments from the command line or a batch file
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "%PSScript%" "%GmailAccount%" "%GmailPassword%" "%Attachment%"
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
pause
EXIT
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:WritePS
SET PSScript=%temp%\temp_SendeMail.ps1
> "%PSScript%" (
    ECHO $Username  = $args[0]
    ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]
    ECHO $Attachment= $args[2]
    ECHO $EmailTo = $Username
    ECHO $EmailFrom  = $Username
    ECHO $Subject = "This email was sent from Powershell script into a batch file with Less Secure Application Enabled"   
    ECHO $Body= "Test Email Sending with a script"  
    ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"  
    ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body^) 
    ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment^)
    ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment^)
    ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587^)
    ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword^) 
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage^)
)
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second You can call this batch file from the command line or you can also save another batch file as **`Sendit.bat`** and execute by double click in order to call the first script with arguments `PS-Gmail-Sender.bat`

```
PS-Gmail-Sender.bat "Mygmail_Account@gmail.com" "MyGmail_Password" "D:\test\myFile.txt"
```

Comment: User is already using PowerShell, so there's no need for a `.bat` script at all.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Yes ! Just this is an option but what i want to say is the most impotant thing about using `smtp.gmail.com` to activate the less secure application !

Comment: omg tysm. I actually needed a .bat file, but both works fine! tysm man.

Comment: finnaly i can make something to spam my friend with lewds

Comment: @MrTortol Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question